# SignalR Self Hosted And Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm trying to make some self hosted SignalR app(Console). But it is not working with Asp.Net MVC 5, i was searched everything.  I was working with this literally 1 day but still it is not working.

I'm using SignalR 2.4.1 both on console and web side.

The startup code on console app is;

```csharp
   class startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            hubConfiguration.EnableJSONP = true;
            HubException exception = new HubException();

            //app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            Console.WriteLine("hub started");
        }
    }
```

On console main;

```csharp
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = @"http://localhost:5693";
            var web = WebApp.Start<startup>(url);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The Test Hub is;

```csharp
    public class testHub : Hub
    {
        public void hopeWorks()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("called");
            Clients.All.Work();
            Clients.Caller.Work();
        }
    }
```

On the Client side is Javascript like that;

```javascript
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log("socket started");
            });
```

I was attached the message sending code to button but it didnt work, so i'm trying on console. 
I'm trying to call it from dev tools, and it is

```
$.connection.testHub.server.hopeWorks();
```

and nothing happens like the image shows.

[image]

I dont know what should i try else, i tried like everything. Searched on google and gone thru next pages.

Sorry for the english btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem with this.
I changed the startup script like this and it works.

```csharp
app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
```

with this;

```csharp
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                HubConfiguration hcf = new HubConfiguration();
                map.RunSignalR();
            });
```

and now it works.